# plot some data such as pairs in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot some data, but I can't.

It is assumed that we have 820 rows in 2 columns, representing the x and y coordinates.

My code is as follows:

```
load('MyMatFileName.mat');
[m , n]=size(inputs);
s = zeros(m,2);
for m=1:820        
    if inputs(m,end-1)<2 &   inputs(m,end)<2
        x = inputs(m,end-1)
        y = inputs(m,end)
        plot(x,y,'r','LineWidth',1.5)
        hold on
    end
end
```

Comment: try `plot(x,y,'or','LineWidth',1.5)`. when you do `plot(x,y,'r','LineWidth',1.5)` you're trying to plot a **line** with a **single point**, which plots nothing... if you want to plot a single point you need to use *markers*, for example `'.'`, `'o'`,...

Comment: ok. it solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited your code and added comments to explain the changes you *could* make, but see below I've also re-written your code to be more like how it *should* be done:

```
load('MyMatFileName.mat');  % It's assumed "inputs" is in here
% You don't use the second size output, so use a tilde ~
[m, ~] = size(inputs);
%s = zeros(m,2); % You never use s...

% Use a different variable for the loop, as m is already the size variable
% I've assumed you wanted ii=1:m rather than m=1:820
figure
hold on   % Use hold on and hold off around all of your plotting
for ii=1:m
    if inputs(m,end-1)<2 && inputs(m,end)<2 % Use double ampersand for individual comparison
        x = inputs(m,end-1)
        y = inputs(m,end)
        % Include the dot . to specify you want a point, not a line!
        plot(x, y, 'r.','LineWidth',1.5)
    end
end
hold off
```

A better way of doing this whole operation in Matlab would be to vectorise your code:

```
load('MyMatFileName.mat');
[m, ~] = size(inputs);
x = inputs(inputs(:,end-1) < 2 & inputs(:,end) < 2, end-1);
y = inputs(inputs(:,end-1) < 2 & inputs(:,end) < 2, end);
plot(x, y, 'r.', 'linewidth', 1.5);
```

Note that this will plot points, if you want to plot the line, use

```
plot(x, y, 'r', 'linewidth', 1.5); % or plot(x, y, 'r-', 'linewidth', 1.5);
```

Comment: Very good. Now I want to find the minimum of points. How can I do it?

Comment: This is literally too short to post on its own: `min(y)`... Please mark this as accepted if it answers your question

Comment: No!
I have some points such as (x(m),y(n)).
Now i want to find minimum of it.
for example :
x = linspace(0,100,500)
y = linspace(0,100,500)
now we have 500 pairs and we want to fine the minimum.
which m(Xi,Yi) is min???

Comment: What do you mean by minimum if not `min`? The minimum `y` value, and its index within `y` can be given by `[miny, idx] = min(y)`, then `[x(idx), y(idx)]` is your minimum point.

Comment: We assumed to have 10 coordinate points.
which index is minimum?

    (1.80010698 ,  4.014570409)
    (9.748210988 , 2.411989898)
    (13.42264438 , 868.0535382)
    (11.24015951 , 3.870002979)
    (1.689561544 , 2.297184285)
    (1.887080244 , 2.019336807)
    (9.932550154 , 1.457111369)
    (9.184472568 , 2.521589242)
    (5.061231021 , 2.800199182)
    (3.343124515 , 2.478806307)

Comment: Have you tried the method in my comment? If what you want is more complicated, then mark this answer as accepted (because it answers your original question) and ask a new question about finding minimums in data.

Comment: I got my answer of the original question. but the continue of the answer is wrong. ok. i ask a new question for finding minimums of points.  Thanks.